# Mapkit Array of Pins with Custom images and Details?

Tags: iphone

Hello i have been trying to find a tutorial that show how to setup an array of locations with details and images and drop the array of pins on the map.

would someone have a simple way of doing this this?
links would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little googling

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/building-an-earthquake-monitor-for-iphone-using-mapkit

you are looking for custom annotations i believe